# wcf host console service code to iis7?

Tags: c#, wcf

I created a console  Application which hosts the service...
now i want to take the service and host it on iis7

I created the .svc file

configured the iis7

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehfhs.jpg

[image]

all the compiled code i put on outside directory :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0gAh.jpg

[image]

and the bin file inside the APP code folder...

**and it tells me :** 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3NKn.jpg

[image]

what am i missing ?

Can i convert console hoster to iis hoster ?

should it have to be website  in the first place ?

should the service also need to have the config ( in my console app it didnt - only the hoster).....?   p.s. as you can see i did clone the config here. ( to the service dir) and also to the output dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be to create a new empty ASP.NET application to which you add a new WCF service. Then simply replace the generated code with the one of your service.

I think the reason why your code doesn't work is because you have an ASP.NET website (and not ASP.NET application) and in your .svc file you are only specifying the name of the service but not the codebehind file that contains it. Since an ASP.NET website is not compiled you need to [specify this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967286.aspx):

```
<% @ServiceHost 
    Service="Service.Class1" 
    Debug="Debug"
    Language="C#" 
    CodeBehind="~/App_Code/Class1.cs"
%>
```

Also you are mentioning some *bin file inside the APP code folder*. If you have some precompiled service in an assembly, this assembly should be inside the ~/bin folder. In a precompiled ASP.NET application you should not have any App_Code folder. It's really 2 different modes: application vs website. Up to you to decide which mode you prefer.

Comment: I had my console hoster. I just want to convert the host from the console to the iis.....Does it have to be an asp.net if i want to host it on iis ? cant it take the service merely?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, yes it has to be an ASP.NET application. There is no such thing as service in IIS. WCF services are hosted in ASP.NET applications in IIS. But as I said I think that you are missing a codebehind directive in your .svc file since you are using an ASP.NET website.

Comment: I also added it before and then removed it back  - still not working. i guess it has to be an asp.net site from the begining.  so what is all about WAS ?? it should be host also services,,,?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, WAS is a special module in IIS which allows you to directly host WCF services that use binary bindings such as netTcpBinding for example.

Comment: So if my console host a service which is netTcpBinding - should i be able to host it on iis7 ? or again , it has to be an asp.net web site which the iis hosts...?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, if you want to use netTcpBinding your only choice is WAS in IIS. You cannot host it as a traditional ASP.NET application.

Comment: sorry to ask you so many questions ...so IIS7 as traditionally - can only run services from asp.net which use httpBasicBindings ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, yes, only HTTP. In your example that's what you are using: `basicHttpBinding` which is SOAP. So it will work in classic ASP.NET.